# SQL Group by need missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a SQL `grade_code` table as below where the `Grade` column is coded with colors (Green, Blue, Red, Yellow):

| ID | State | School | Grade | Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CA | CAS | 1 | Green |
| 2 | CA | CAS | 1 | Green |
| 3 | CA | CAS | 2 | Blue |
| 4 | GA | GAC | 3 | Red |
| 5 | GA | GAC | 2 | Blue |
| 6 | GA | GAC | 3 | Red |

I was able to get to the below results by using group by

```
SELECT
    State, School, Code,
    COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grade_code) AS '%' 
FROM
    grade_code
GROUP BY
    State, School, Code
```

| State | School | Code | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | CAS | Green | 75% |
| CA | CAS | Blue | 25% |
| GA | GAC | Red | 75% |
| GA | GAC | Blue | 25% |

But I would like the results of the missing `Code` as well:

| State | School | Code | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CA | CAS | Green | 75% |
| CA | CAS | Blue | 25% |
| CA | CAS | Yellow | 0% |
| CA | CAS | Red | 0% |
| GA | GAC | Red | 75% |
| GA | GAC | Blue | 25% |
| GA | GAC | Yellow | 0% |
| GA | GAC | Green | 0% |

Comment: You would have to add a LEFT join to your lookup table.

Comment: i don't get your expected data with your query?

Comment: You can't select rows that are not there, you need to either create them or preferably select from other tables you have that store the lists of available states/schools. please include this sample data.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH grade_code(ID,State,School,Grade,  Code)AS
(
  SELECT  1,    'CA',   'CAS',  1,  'Green' UNION ALL
  SELECT  2,    'CA',   'CAS',  1,  'Green' UNION ALL
  SELECT  3,    'CA',   'CAS',  2,  'Blue' UNION ALL
  SELECT  4,    'GA',   'GAC',  3,  'Red' UNION ALL
  SELECT  5,    'GA',   'GAC',  2,  'Blue' UNION ALL
  SELECT  6,    'GA',   'GAC',  3,  'Red' 
),
ALL_COMBINATIONS AS
(
   SELECT S.State,SC.School,CODE.Code
   FROM grade_code S
   CROSS JOIN
   (
     SELECT DISTINCT School
     FROM grade_code
   )SC  
   CROSS JOIN
   (
    SELECT 'Red' AS Code UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Blue' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Green' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Yellow'
   )CODE
 )

SELECT SQ.State,SQ.School,SQ.Code,SQ.CNTT FROM
(
  SELECT GR.State,GR.School,GR.Code,COUNT(*)CNTT
  FROM grade_code AS GR
  GROUP BY GR.State,GR.School,GR.Code
)SQ
UNION ALL
SELECT X.State,X.School,X.Code,0
FROM
(
   SELECT A.STATE,A.School,A.Code
   FROM ALL_COMBINATIONS AS A
   EXCEPT
   SELECT G.State,G.School,G.Code
   FROM grade_code AS G
)X
ORDER BY SQ.State,SQ.School,SQ.Code
```

Sorry, I didn't understand your percentage calculations,but hope something like this can help you

Answer (score 2):

In a normal situation, you would have separate tables to store (1) the state/school tuples (2) the list of codes.

You would then `cross join` the two reference tables, then bring the dataset with a `left join`. As for the ratio of each code in its school, we can use window functions rather than a subquery:

```
select s.state, s.school, c.code,
    100.0 * count(t.code) 
          / nullif(sum(count(t.code)) over(partition by s.state, s.school), 0) pct
from schools s
cross join codes c 
left join mytable t
    on  t.state  = s.state
    and t.school = s.school
    and t.code   = c.code
group by s.state, s.school, c.code
```

Without reference tables, you can either select distinct values from the table, or use a fixed list of literals. Here is an approach that mixes both:

```
select s.state, s.school, c.code,
    100.0 * count(t.code) 
          / nullif(sum(count(t.code)) over(partition by s.state, s.school), 0) pct
from (
    select distinct school, state from mytable
) s
cross join ( values
    ('Red'),
    ('Blue'),
    ('Green'),
    ('Yellow')
) c(code)
left join mytable t
    on  t.state  = s.state
    and t.school = s.school
    and t.code   = c.code
group by s.state, s.school, c.code
```